# Python and GTK3 - best way to set a button pressed manually?

Tags: python-2.7, signals, gtk3, emit

I've searched but cannot find a good explanation on how to do it.

I have built a physical MIDI (serial) console, to control the gui i'm writing in python2.7 (2.7 due to a library..) and Gtk3.

I can control scales and toggle buttons, but I don't know how to set a button as pressed and emit the relative signal.

I understand I have to create my own 'copy' of the signal and then emit it, but I don't understand how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you *really* should convert to Python3. If I'm not mistaken, end of this year, support for 2.x stops.

To 'activate' a togglebutton, use the `set_active` method:

```
tbtn = Gtk.ToggleButton("I'm toggleable")
tbtn.set_active(True)
```

On changes, it will activate the `toggled` signal for the button.
Do a `tbtn.get_active()` call to get its state.

By the way, if you want to make sure `toggled` is triggered, you 
might want to check its state first (before `.set_active`).

(Change the Gtk capitalization to what corresponds to which Python
you are using. I use introspection and Gtk3)

EDIT:

The code below takes a ToggleButton, and makes it into a normal button
(more or less), by subclassing it and removing the original handling.
As it is, it does not emit the toggled signal, but that wouldn't be
too difficult to add.

The top Button (btn1) is a normal button and it activates the bottom
one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_button_press.py
#
#  Copyright 2019 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
#


import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GooCanvas', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GooCanvas

class My_button(Gtk.ToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(My_button, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.connect("button_press_event", self.on_btn2_press)
        self.connect("button_release_event", self.on_btn2_released)

    def on_btn2_press(self, btn, event):
        self.pressed2_at = event.time
        btn.set_active(True)
        return True

    def on_btn2_released(self, btn, event):
        print("Release2 after", event.time - self.pressed2_at)
        btn.set_active(False)
        return True


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.btn1 = Gtk.Button("Button1")
        self.btn1.connect("clicked", self.on_btn1_clicked)

        self.btn2 = My_button(label = "Victim")

        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox(spacing = 4)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.btn1, False, False, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.btn2, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.show_all()


    def on_btn1_clicked(self, btn):
        self.btn2.set_active(True)


    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in my explaining. I've no problem with the toggle button, but I have to trigger the "Button-pressed" state of a simple push button (not toggle..), which doesn't have a .set_active() method.  About python2.7, unfortunately it doesn't depend on me, but on the HAL python library (LinuxCNC) which doesn't work on python 3.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for the example you gave me, and for the hint of transforming a Toggle button to a Push button with the set_active() method. It exactly meets my needs.

Comment: A question on your example: after creating an instance of My_Button, I need to reuse the button_press_event and button_release_event, but events do not propagate after being read in the class. Is there a way to let the signal be read again?

Comment: That should be possible - after all, the button still responds to pressing & releasing. You will probably have to define a `connect` method yourself. I have little time today - maybe I'll be able to test the idea tomorrow.